# Load js dynamically in an Node.js received from mongoDB (hosted @Azure)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a Node.js server hosted in Azure

Developers should be able to write JavaScript satisfying an API and upload it to my MongoDB hosted somewhere else.

My Node.js server now gets triggered and picks the right logic from the MongoDB.

- How can I execute this Code dynamically the best way?
- Use Eval? Or can I load the file in MainMemory and execute it?

The loaded code must be able to access other methods running on the Server (the ones documented in the API for the developer)

Comment: Are your node.js code snippets are stored on mongoDB, and you want to receive them from DB and execute them in the Node.js application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a pretty neat solution:

- transform the JavaScript syntax to "Node.js" syntax
- write the module with the fs-library to a file
- "require" the created file to a variable
- execute the logic of the variable
- delete the file afterwards

--> you can now debug the code unlike with using "eval"

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are right, we can leverage `eval()` to execute the javascript code from string, if you need to access to the local scope. You can refer to https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_vm_runinthiscontext_code_options for the detailed explanation.

Here is my test file in MongoDB:

```
{
  "id": "123",
  "code": "someFuc()"
}
```

And test code snippet in Node.js:

```
function someFuc(){
    console.log("this is consoled from node.js application");
}
...
//  file results query from db
...
var code = results[0].code;
console.log(code);
eval(code);
```

Comment: is that the only way?

Comment: Currently I haven't found a better one or another workaround.